# JavaScript variable scope

Tags: javascript, extjs, closures, scope

I have declared var1 inside the function. However, when i try to assign a value in inner_function2, it seems another var1 is create instead of referencing to the first one.

```
var func1 = function(response) {

    var var1;

    function inner_function2(param) {

        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url:'',
            params: param,
            success:function(result, request) { 
                var1 = a;
                }
            });
    }   

}()
```

Comment: I suppose the invalid syntax if a copy+paste issue? Also, how do you determine that "it seems another var is created"?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you specify the scope explicitly in your code. you can do like:

```
var func1 = function(response) {
  var var1;
  var outer_scope = this;

  function inner_func2(param) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
      url: '',
      params: param,
      scope: outer_scope,
      success: function(result, request) {
        var1 = a;
      }
    });
  }
}()
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 4):

`success` callback of `Ext.Ajax.request` is called after AJAX request has been returned. This means, the function that called it (both `func1()` and `inner_function2()` have already returned, and their scope was deleted.

Let's try to show a sequence of events

1. `func1()` is called
2. local variable `var1` is declared
3. `inner_function2()` is called (I'm assuming you do call it somewhere)
4. `Ext.Ajax.request()` is called, with `success` callback declared
5. `inner_function2()` ends - the AJAX request is running in the background
6. `func1()` ends, local variable `var1` is deleted (it still is available in callback scope though)- the AJAX request is running in the background
7. AJAX request finishes - `success` callback is called. <s>Since there is no local variable `var1` a global variable is created and assigned value of `a`</s> (see the comments below why this is deleted). Local variable `var1` is still available in callback's scope, but once the callback ends, the variable is no longer available anywhere, so you can't use it.

Remember that 'A' in AJAX stands for 'Asynchronous'.

Comment: Is this something specific to ExtJS? I'd be surprised if it was, because usually this is covered by closures. Yes, the `success` callback is called long after `inner_function2` has returned, but closures should keep `var1` alive within the callback.

Comment: @deceze: If the assignemnt was `a = var1` then yes. But since it's the other way round it is not. Come on. how would you use this variable anyway, if it's no longer available ANYWHERE?

Comment: @CKeven: because that's how asynchronous calls work. func1() will not wait for AJAX request to finish. It just initiates it, and then goes on with it's work.

Comment: Nonsense, a closured variable is a closured variable no matter which side of an assignment it's on. I do agree that the real problem is that the variable is not accessed in the right scope/right timing, but the assignment *does* assign to `var var1`.

Comment: @deceze: Maybe you are right. I admit I did not test that. [edit] Yes, you are right, the global variable is not created.

Comment: The solution is to create the var1 outside of the func1 function declaration (or to skip the var in `var var1`, it is then created globaly but thats not a very nice or readable solution).

Comment: @David: beter solution would be to split whatever func1() is doing into two functions, one of which is being called from the callback.